# First entry in a city not associated to Russian visa

Tags: visas, russia

I'm planning to visit Russia again, and I applied for a tourist visa for my destination (Yekaterinburg, no other destination listed in my invitation voucher).

I'm now considering which fly to get to my destination, and I'm evaluating a 7h+ layover in Moscow Vnukovo. But since I won't be forced to change terminal and to redo check-in, I just realized that if I want to visit Moscow briefly I'll have to go through a border check that I otherwise probably wouldn't have to do.

I know from elsewhere that visiting other places in Russia is not a big deal (as long as you don't stay more than 7 working days, and if so you should have a registration for the main place that you've been documented as staying in), but in this case it might be a bit different, since that'd be the first port of entry.

I presume it's possible that the border check personnel (unlike other policemen) might actually have information about the cities that I declared as destinations for my visa, and that they could then reject me if I'd try to exit there.

Do you think this is actually what would happen, and it's not worth the risk? (and the risk would just be to have to spent the full length of the layover at the airport, right?) Should I rather pick another (less convenient) flight with a shorter layover?

Comment: Eh? If you fly to Yekaterinburg via Moscow then you will go through immigration control at Moscow.

Comment: gotcha, I've also seen this other discussion now: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g298484-i718-k6505008-o20-Vnukovo_Airport-Moscow_Central_Russia.html

it seems that I might have to go through customs and retrieve my baggage in Ekb, but I'll clear passport checks in Moscow.

Since vnukovo only has a single terminal I thought that there'd be no separation between international and internal flights, and that confused me a bit

Comment: @berdario Ive never been to Vnukovo but you must consider the traffic in Moscow (which is insane). From DMO airport it takes me 2 hours one way, just to get to our central apartment. If you plan to go to red square it is 40 km and one hour away from Vnukovo, during light traffic. I would assume a minimum 2 hour taxi ride, to and from Vnukovo. You'll also need to check back into the airport with your bags atleast one hour before departure, and it can take an hour just to get through the lines. So you will be very rushed and pressured. I would just stay at the airport and relax.